# Sharing Apps between Accounts (due to user age)

Tags: applications, 8.1-oreo, accounts

Good Morning Everyone,

Before I ask the question about sharing apps between Android users, I wanted to quantify the use case. This is because I don't want to come across as trying to illegally distribute apps in any way.

We have a tablet in the house that was specifically purchased as my child has a learning development disability. That means I have purchased a lot of apps from the Play Store to find things that were to help this. In the past it was easy; they were not adept enough to work out how to buy things on tablets. Now she is older and wiser, as is their sibling. Both are still single digit in age.

So the tablet is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A6, running Android 8.1 - stock updates, no root, no modifications.

In the past, when multi-user first appeared, I was able to buy apps from my Play Store, and it would appear on her non-admin user. I understand that this is now not possible though, and certainly I have not been able to achieve this with anything I have downloaded in recent memory.

The problem is though that both children are still under 10, so can not have their own Play Store account to have a *Family* set up.

So is there anyway to get around this? preferably without rooting the tablet? I am quite happy to wipe their account from the tablet if that helps things.

Comment: Copying apk from admin to other users is doable, so is their installation. But I don't actually know how this "share" feature you  are talking about used to work. Did it involve sharing not just the app but also its data (that is, whatever you did in the app using admin account was visible to child user)? Another issue is licensing check.Two accounts one license may not work for some apps,depending upon what license  verification  parameters are used by an app.

Comment: I will be honest and say "I can't remember either." I am sure it was just in Settings when multi-user came in, with a list of apps you could expose to all users. Apparently Google has a Family management option for under 13s but it looks like I also have to share my payment method with them.